# Сайт на PHP для GET запроса

Tags: php, get

Код сайта [www.izhcult.ru](http://www.izhcult.ru) выводит на страницу IP User-Sgent и Geo

Как изменить этот код, что бы я мог получать эти данные GET запросом

```
<?php

$client  = @$_GET['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
$forward = @$_GET['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
$remote  = @$_GET['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$result  = array('country'=>'', 'city'=>'');
 
if(filter_var($client, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) $ip = $client;
elseif(filter_var($forward, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)) $ip = $forward;
else $ip = $remote;
 
$ip_data = @json_decode(file_get_contents("http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=".$ip));    
if($ip_data && $ip_data->geoplugin_countryName != null)
{
    $result = $ip_data->geoplugin_countryName;
}

echo $remote, $result;

?>
```

Вот я изменил SERVER на GET возвращает только страну. Я просто совсем далек от PHP

Мне необходимо, что бы возвращал 145.45.81:Russia

Comment: замените `$_SERVER` на `$_GET`

Comment: <h1 class="ip">
</h1>

<h2 class="ua">User-Agent:

</h2>


<h2 class="country">  Country:
Russia - 

Вот такой ответ возвращает, как сделать, что бы чисто IP  и GEO

Comment: А сейчас ты каким запросом их получаешь? Не тем же самым GET?

Comment: Я из программы получаю. Я сделал другую страничку izhcult.ru/get.php

Comment: Мне нужно что бы возвращал чисто так -   192.158.12.142, Russia Moscow

Comment: Верни SERVER обратно, это тебе чушь посоветовали.

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо!